# microsoft office onSend feature does not allow to send mail if dialog is opened through displayDialogAsync API

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to implement On Send feature in outlook Add-in.
All prerequisite are done. It is working fine as normal scenario as mentioned in the documentation.But for my case the requirement is this:

> If the Body contains any 'Block Word' I want to show to the user a
>   Dialog box (using displayDialogAsync API) with two options 'Continue'
>   and 'Cancel'. Without dialog box it allows to send Mail but with
>   dialog it is not working.

```
var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

function validateBody(event) {
    mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, 
   checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
}

function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(bodyAsyncResult) {
    var listOfBlockedWords = new Array("blockedword", "blockedword1", "blockedword2");
    var wordExpression = listOfBlockedWords.join('|');

    // \b to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b.
    // i to perform case-insensitive search.
    var regexCheck = new RegExp('\\b(' + wordExpression + ')\\b', 'i');
    var checkBody = regexCheck.test(asyncResult.value);

    if (checkBody) {
        mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Blocked words have been found in the body of this email. Please remove them.' });
        var dialog;
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(location.origin+'#/urlpath?queryString', {
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            displayInIframe: true
        }, function(asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            //used - Office.context.ui.messageParent() to acces the following block;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function(args) {
                 if(args.status){
                   // Allow send.
                   bodyAsyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
                 }else{
                   // Block send.
                   bodyAsyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
                 }
                 dialog.close();
                 event.completed();
            });
        });

    }else{

      // Allow send.
      bodyAsyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    }
```

Comment: i think this is designed. you have to send a message to your opening context and let it call the office api.

Comment: I have already used Office.context.ui.messageParent() to send the message but but after that asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true }); is not working

Comment: This is definitely a supported scenario and a number of add-in developers do this, so feels like a bug with your code somewhere. Where does your code break down? Does it hit the args.status if statement? Does it ever go into the completed function? I'm wondering if you passing around the completed event is messing something up. Have you tried keeping the event a global variable instead of passing it across?

Comment: As per the documentation the event is passed as an parameter, So i have implemented like that. After so many attempt i found that the "event" is accessible only inside the following callback function - 
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, function(arg){
     // Block send.
     bodyAsyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
});

but it is called for events only.

Comment: Yes args.status hits in if statement and it goes inside, after that it breaks.

Comment: could you please clarify what breaks? Are you saying bodyAsyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true }); gives an error or it doesn't do anything?  In addition, it is unclear which event you are trying to complete in the line 'event.completed();'  Unless I miss something, there's no event variable that code block.