# Office add-in Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync window will not appear with "On Send" feature activated

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to add an Office Dialog window to the ["No Send" tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send). I can run the tutorial perfectly and the blocked words are blocked as expected. However, when I attempt to modify the tutorial to add a displayDialogAsync(), the dialog code is completely ignored, and I never see a pop-up window at all. Here are my modifications, with displayInIFrame set to false:

```
function validateBody(asyncResult) {

        Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Processing mail about to be sent.' });
            var dialog

            var url = "https://localhost:3000/test.html"
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { width: 80, height: 60, displayInIframe: true }, function(result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        console.log("FAILED: " + result.error.message)
                        reject(new DialogError(result.error.message, result.error))
                }
                 dialog = result.value
          dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, args => {
                                    console.log("MSG RECVD")
                                    console.log(args.status)
                                    if(true){ // just for testing; both branches cause the Send button to grey out
                                            asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
                                    }
                            })
                    dialog.close()

            })


   //asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
        }
```

If I change displayInFrame to true, I *will* make it into the function, and I see an error:

> The operation failed because this add-in already has an active dialog.

I've verified that my test HTML exists and is reachable by browser. I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951091/microsoft-office-onsend-feature-does-not-allow-to-send-mail-if-dialog-is-opened).

Comment: What client are you doing this on? (OWA, Mac, Desktop Windows, etc.) Since displayDialogAsync is an async call, is it possible you are calling event.completed() before you are giving it a chance to finish?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 77 on OS X Mojave. If I remove the event.completed, I do see the window flash quickly before closing, but then if I try to send a subsequent email, the Send button greys out upon being pressed. Is that expected? I will modify my question to show more source code. Thank you.

Comment: Send Button getting greyed out is an expected behavior, If onSend is running and you click on send button, send buttons gets greyed out until the mail is sent. I tried your piece of code and i do see the displayDialogAsync Window.